# Получение URL (с которого был послан запрос) на сервере

Tags: redirect, php, http

Или иначе, как сделать запрос к одному скрипту, выполнить его, а после отправить клиенту туже страницу, с которой запрос был сделан? Сейчас делаю через HTTP заголовки, но вот как указать туже страницу не знаю.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

может

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

В элементе `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` приводится адрес страницы, с которой посетитель пришёл на данную страницу. Переход должен осуществляться по ссылке.

Comment: Если вернет URL с которого был запрос сделан, то поняли меня верно.

Comment: попробуйте

Comment: Преход осуществляется черех форму ... Ни че не возвращает...

Comment: тогда отправьте пост запросом вместе с формой, скрытое поле с адресом текущей страницы.

    $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

Comment: Верно все. Благодарю!